# Book Recommendation for Conics section specifically

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, book-recommendation

So , I will be completing S.L Loney Coordinate geometry book very soon and I feel like I need more practice in Conics especially in Ellipse and Hyperbolae section , Can anyone suggest me a problem solving book in Conics (Not theory, Because S.L loney has a very vast theory and sufficient for my preparation) and the level of the book must up to a competitive level exam or Olympiad. Thank you:)

Comment: Googling (in Google Books, and regular google with "archive.org" included), I immediately found: **A Collection of Examples and Problems on Conics and Some of the Higher Plane Curves** by Ralph A. Roberts (1882; [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/acollectionexam00robegoog) and [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=E2ptAAAAMAAJ)). See also his 1884 follow-up book: [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/acollectionexam01robegoog) and [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=Fhx2erSEbWkC).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks a lot sir , just saw the content of the book really helpful for my preparation  . Thanks a lot again :))